# How to use PREFIX that created by autoconf in source file

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

Autoconf could help to generate `configure` script which accepts an option called `--prefix` in general. In this way, users could specific a path where programs/data installed.

In my program, I'd like to refer the location where data files are installed. In plain Makefile, it could be done like

gcc -DPREFIX "/usr/share"

and in the source file, data path is generated in

#define DATAPATH PREFIX "/data"

with autoconf, how could I use the path specified by `--prefix` in source code? Is there a pre-defined MACRO for this?

Comment: What if the application was relocated/repackaged after `make install`? the compile/make install time --prefix is something you shouldn't rely on at runtime.

Comment: The idea was about referring some images files which need to be load at runtime. These images files are installed into "/usr/share/pkgname/images. What is the best solution to do this then?

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved by `automake`. Define `AM_CFLAGS` like

```
AM_CFLAGS = -DPKGDATA=$(pkgdata)
```

automake will extend $(pkgdata) to `/usr/share/<pkgname>/` if the `--prefix` is `/usr/`.

Comment: I'd suggest using `AM_CPPFLAGS` - this is a preprocessor definition after all - and it will appear in C/C++ compilations. In fact, many useful variables set with `--prefix`, etc., are [already available](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Installation-Directory-Variables) to the `Makefile.am`.